# cannot read SSL keyfile.kyr

Tags: ssl, ibm-domino

my domino server cannot read SSL keyfile.kyr ? error message->HTTP Server: File does
not exist, key ring file [keyfileesh.kyr], [Default Server]

1) troubleshooting done so far

2) checked names.nsf for configurations - Using Web Configuration View

3) Check that the keyfile.kyr and keyfile.sth are present in the domino\data
directory. Created new .kyr file and .sth files - to rule out possible
corruption issues

4) checked file persmissions, everything looks good.

5) moved .kyr and .sth file out of domino directory.

Give the full path to key file in ->SSL key file name

6) replaced names.nsf with a new replica ..

problem still persists... thanks for your help

any ideas ?!!

Comment: The error message says that the file is set to have the name keyfileesh.kyr. You call it keyfile.kyr in step 3. Is this the issue?

Comment: Is it a linux server? Then you might have misses to set the rights and the owner for he two files. And of course Per Henrik is right: if there is a typo in the name of the kyr- file it will not work as well...

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten - i dont think there is a typo error.

Comment: @TorstenLink - no it's not linux box. 
and thanks for your help guyz

Comment: What's the actual file called? and what is it called in the configurations document?

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten - we used process monitor to see if domino is making any attempt to use files .. and it(domino) did - after collecting logs and search for .kyr file - it was clear at this point there is something at OS level not letting domino use those files.. further digging revealed that antivirus had quarantineed some .dll file ... now eveything works fine. cheers guyz .. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVED:
we used process monitor to see if domino is making any attempt to use files .. and it(domino) did - after collecting logs and search for .kyr file - it was clear at this point there is something wrong at OS level not letting domino use those files.. further digging revealed that antivirus had quarantineed some .dll files ... now eveything works fine.

cheers guyz .. thanks for your help